# Enum as Generic parameter in Interface. Use in default implementation

Tags: java, interface, enums

Hello I try pass to interface as parameter `Enum` object, and after this parse him to `List<Enum>` in body **default function interface**. So my interface looks like below

```
public interface SpecificObject<T extends Enum<T>>{
        default List<Enum> asMyList(){
        List<Enum> list = Arrays.asList(T.values()); // not works
        return list;
    }
}
```

After this I have a plane use in this way

```
class SomeObject implements SpecificObject<MyEnum>{
      public SomeObject()
     // dont' must Overwrite because I use as default
}
```

And somewhere in code usage, just as below

```
SpecificObject specificObject = new someObject SomeObject();
List<Enum> list = someObject.asMyList();
```

Is it possible in JAVA 8?

Comment: Try it, and then you will know.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Use EnumSet as an example of how you should do that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> List<T> getEnumConstants(T object) {
    assert object != null;
    Class<T> type = object.getClass();
    T[] constants = type.getEnumConstants();
    return Arrays.asList(constants);
}
```

Not tested, but this looks workable. The List is however as inflexible as the original `T[]`.

Packing the function in an interface as default method will not bring any advantage.

Note `Class.getEnumConstants` is not typed for Enum, and will yield `null` for non-enums.

*(When staying in one specific Enum, EnumSet (a kind of bitset) and EnumMap (a kind of array) is often quite efficient and fast.)*